# github----git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: github, ssh

I google online to find the solution and tried as this link https://docs.github.com/cn/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

But it didn't work.

1. When I type `ssh -vT git@github.com`, the result:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/zetlin/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/zetlin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: /home/zetlin/.ssh/config line 12: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [141.164.49.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github type 0
debug1: identity file /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:UIDrRc6***************sgm7HpmED92IuKCo
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/zetlin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github RSA SHA256:7O+NeSr******************1A8rOv6l+amG9s explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Zelin_Xu@********.com RSA SHA256:cc95TN**********************N9E61y1Z9kbGA agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github RSA SHA256:7O+NeSr*****************1A8rOv6l+amG9s explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: Zelin_Xu@*********.com RSA SHA256:cc95TN*******************9E61y1Z9kbGA agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

[image]

2. When type `ssh-add -l -E sha256`
   the result is same as github ssh keys
   [image]
3. I tried as here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey, when type  `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, then type`ssh-add -l -E sha256`  , output is `The agent has no identities.`
   when type `ssh -T git@github.com`, the terminator ask me to input the  `git@github.com's password:`  , either the password to login in the github website or the password to ssh-gen(actually no password) is not OK. Which password should I type here?

```
Agent pid 16629
➜  apollo git:(predtr) ssh-add -l -E sha256  
The agent has no identities.
➜  apollo git:(predtr) ssh-agent bash      
(base) zetlin@zetlin-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~/Code/github/apollo$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_github
Identity added: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github (linzexu@126.com)
(base) zetlin@zetlin-HP-Z4-G4-Workstation:~/Code/github/apollo$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.com's password: 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Update:

4. Follow the tips, maybe the configuration is conflicting, I delete the configure files& keys files in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` & known_hosts in `/home/zetlin/known_hosts`, then command `ssh -vT git@github.com`, the result:

```
➜  ~ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/zetlin/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/zetlin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: /home/zetlin/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [141.164.49.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github type 0
debug1: identity file /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:UIDr***************************92IuKCo
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/zetlin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github RSA SHA256:7O+NeSr****************1A8rOv6l+amG9s explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: Zelin_Xu@******************.com RSA SHA256:cc95TN*****************61y1Z9kbGA agent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github RSA SHA256:7O+NeSr**************Ov6l+amG9s explicit agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: Zelin_Xu@********.com RSA SHA256:cc95TNApI**********************1y1Z9kbGA agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@github.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@github.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I still don't know the password

update:

5. I could git clone 'https' but not 'ssh'

Comment: `debug1: /home/zetlin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com` You have a special ssh configuration for github.com, could it be interfering? `debug1: Will attempt key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github` That's the key it is trying, but it is not being accepted. `git@github.com's password` once ssh has run out of keys to try it will try to log in with a password, but that isn't going to work. It seems your key is wrong.

Comment: This is the config file(/home/zetlin/.ssh/config)
```Host github.com
    HostName  github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github
Host chshyfvm0043
    HostName chshyfvm0043
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_TFS
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Host *
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1```

Acturally, I don't know the keys: 
```debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:UIDrRc6jWXyhoy0cRkrtYw50F2Zsgm7HpmED92IuKCo```
The other key is same as id_github.pub and ssh keys in github.com

Comment: As your reminder, I find There is another config file(/etc/ssh/ssh_config),  is it caused by the config file? How should I change it?
```Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes```

Comment: `/home/zetlin/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` are merged together with `/home/zetlin/.ssh/config` overriding anything in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Your config has you using `~/.ssh/id_github` as your key, which seems correct. And your debug log indicates it is trying that key. It seems the key is not correct. Does `~/.ssh/id_github.pub` match [the public key you added to Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)?

Comment: Yes, id_github.pub match with the public key that I added to github. ```Will attempt key: /home/zetlin/.ssh/id_github RSA SHA256:7O+NeSr*********************+amG9s``` I found another keys in the log that I don't know: debug1: ```Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:UIDr*******************IuKCo```